# I want to make an option compulsory on my registration page

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to make the option "i found kiabza through" compulsory on my registration page, so that is everyone has to fill it when they register. Also this option was added as a custom addon by our developer, but since they have left i need your help to figure this problem. For your reference i have added the link and screenshot below. Thanks
https://www.kiabza.com/customer/account/create/

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code of that phtml file to your question?

Comment: This is not the actual code. Post the actual code to your question please.

Comment: Where can i find the actual code and when i use path finder it shows me this location, please help i am totally new in magento

Comment: Edit the first option (of the form select box, not the list-item) in your .phtml file and try adding value="" to it instead of just leaving it as value. That makes it `<option value=""></option>` in your case.

Comment: When I click on Request OTP, Only required field is Mobile number.